# How to generate a random key with a format in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made some research and couldn’t find what I need, basically I would like to generate a random key that has the following format XXX-XXX-XXXX

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a quick Javascript solution:

```js
let r = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 3) + "-" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 3) + "-" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 4);
console.log(r.toUpperCase());
```

I added the toUpperCase() since your asked for XXX-XXX-XXXX and not xxx-xxx-xxxx.

Hope it helps !

EDIT: This method is not cryptographically secure. If you need to generate a random key for anything relating to security, use the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) instead.

Comment: Thank you! I will test it today and give you a feedback

Comment: Cool, don't hesitate to ask if you have any questions or if it didn't work for your situation.

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but @WordRearranger why did you do .toString(36)? Why not just .toString()? Sorry, I'm a complete JS noob

Comment: @HelloWorld Math.random() gives numbers. Since we want a random key with numbers and characters, we can use the "radix" parameter of toString() to change the value. In theory any radix would work but 36 is a good one to generate a nice random list of characters. This link might help you understand a little better what I'm trying to explain: https://dev.to/mondirhallouli/explain-jss-radix-in-parseintstr-radix-like-im-five-49ho

Comment: this is pseudo-random, not random. See [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code, it uses the node module [randomatic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomatic).

```
const randomize = require("randomatic");
let random = randomize("A0", 10); //will generate a 10-character, uppercase alpha-numeric randomized string
random =
  random.slice(0, 3) + "-" + random.slice(3, 6) + "-" + random.slice(6, 10);
console.log(random); //1WX-BTV-BZTL
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Node's `crypto` module.

```
const {
  randomBytes,
} = await import('node:crypto');

randomBytes(5, (err, buf) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  let output = buf.toString('hex');
  console.log(output[0]+output[1]+output[2]+"-"+output[3]+output[4]+output[5]+"-"+output[6]+output[7]+output[8]+output[9])
});
```

Returns `9fa-a46-4519`